# Black mod diamonds?

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

Mod diamonds are black on the mobile site of Stack compared to blue on the desktop and apps. Is it meant to be black on the mobile site and blue everywhere else?

[image]

Comment: Anna's diamond looks good in black, but still... :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Aw, nicest thing anyone's ever said to me. ;)

Comment: Maybe she's taken up skiing for the winter? :-)

Comment: These diamonds signify possessed mods.  Do not mess with them under any circumstances.

Comment: @Jamal in that case  there are a lot of possessed mods here... http://i.stack.imgur.com/SaRGl.png

Comment: Mobile web does not show [sites styles](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/1885/10051), the diamond is the least problem.

Comment: They're dark orange for me in Chrome on Android -- been like that for at least a year and still annoying.  (They were properly blue before that.)  Somebody blamed device or browser fonts when I asked about it.