# Missing "start a bounty" link network wide

Tags: bug, bounties

I've currently placed a bounty on Math.SE (First bounty I've ever placed if I'm correct) and wanted to place another on SO but couldn't, I've tried looking at few questions all older than 48 hours (some frequent/unanswered/hot including my older questions) and none had the "start a bounty" button. I've checked both IPS and Astronomy also and couldn't place bounty. I've also tried to place another on Math.SE (but couldn't).

From the tour/help page it says that an User can have at most 3 active bounties so I'm baffled since I only have 1 active bounty.

I've found the link [Missing "start a bounty" link on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54726/missing-start-a-bounty-link-on-stackoverflow) perhaps this has to do something with me having an old account and never casting a bounty before?

Comment: No repro. Most likely some userscript/browser plugin you installed and forgot about, which mess with page content. (e.g. SOUP)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Perhaps but I doubt it, I've tried both chrome and IE, I've also tried incognito mode (and all my extensions are disabled in incognito).

Comment: Still happening? What about here in MSE? e.g. in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245978/black-mod-diamonds), sure you don't see "start a bounty" below the "add a comment" link below the question? If no luck, browse directly to https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/bounty/245978 and say what you see in the drop down list?

Comment: Also note that the bounty link color is hard coded to black, so if you're using dark theme in your browser, you won't see the link.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've just noticed it, what put me off was that the start a bounty link on mobile is inline with "share edit delete..." and not black color. Anyway thanks and if you want you can post an answer.

Comment: Oh, you never mentioned you're on mobile. Feel free to post self answer, after all you "solved" it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike on the mobile view the "start a bounty" is located under the comments and not inline with "share edit..." like on the mobile view.

Comment: I hate this position of the start a bounty link. I wish they would [move it to a better position](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/can-we-move-start-a-bounty-to-a-more-intuitive-location).

Comment: @KodosJohnson Agreed.